# Расположение картинки из одного блока поверх другого блока

Tags: html, css

Есть 2 блока. в 1ом есть картинка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

паддингом двигаю картинку вниз

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать картинку поверх второго блока ?

Comment: z-index может быть ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще руку положить на второй див и поднять вверх либо как писали выше задавать жёсткий z-index

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  top: -34px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.first {
  background-color: blue;
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(30deg);
      top: -34px;
      }
    30% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      top: -64px;
      }
    70% {
      transform: rotate(-10deg);
      top: 20px;
      }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(30deg);
      top: -34px;
      }
}

.second {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"><span></span></div>
```